# Bind control to JavaScript file

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I had JavaScript slide show which had Image and text .But I want to mange js code to retrieve it's data(image, text) from database by code .please anyone help more it more difficult.

aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">


<div class="hom_scrooler_con tm10 "><script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroller.js"></script>

<div class="hom_but_a "><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image9','','images/home-bu_pro_r.jpg',1)"><img src="images/home-bu_pro.jpg" alt="#" name="Image9" width="134" height="34" border="0" id="Image9" /></a></div>
<div class="hom_but_a"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image8','','images/home-bu_news.jpg',1)"><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image8','','images/home-bu_news.jpg',1)"></a><a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image8','','images/home-bu_npro_r.jpg',1)"><img src="images/home-bu_npro.jpg" alt="#" name="Image8" width="134" height="34" border="0" id="Image8" /></a></div>
<div class="hom_but_a"><img src="images/home-bu_news.jpg" width="134" height="34" border="0" /></div>
 </div> 


</form>
```

JS:

```
sts_bs("jwscroller2dbd",[20080623,"images/","","blank.gif",0,1,0,50,"50%","left",2,3,298,199,1,10,0,0,0,2000,1,12,2,
"stEffect(\"scroll(Rate=24,enabled=0,Duration=0.50)\")",-2,60],["none",1,"#454545","transparent","","no-repeat"]);
sts_sca(["center","middle","center","middle"],["aro-lft.png","aro-lftr.png","arrowl_gray.gif",56,55,"aro-rt.png","aro-rtr.png","arrowr_gray.gif",55,51]);
sts_tbd([1],["solid",1,"#454545",5,"round_tl.gif","round_tr.gif","round_br.gif","round_bl.gif","transparent","round_t.gif",
"repeat","transparent","round_r.gif","repeat","transparent","round_b.gif","repeat","transparent","round_l.gif","repeat"]);
sts_ai("i0",[0,"New Sharp Copiers Now 2\r\n\r\nHas been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever 
 when an unknown printer.Simply dummy text of","#","_self","media3_07.png",298,197,"left"],["transparent"
,"bold 10pt Verdana,Arial","#666666","none","bold 10pt Verdana,Arial","#666666","none"]);
sts_ai("i1",[,"New Sharp Copiers \r\n\r\nHas been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever  when an unknown printer.Simply
 dummy text of",,,"media3_08.png"],[,,,,"italic bold 10pt Verdana,Arial"],"i0","i0");
sts_es();
```

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to read through this? At least format it for readability, if not cut it down to the only parts that are relevant.

Comment: @ oded i can't do this so i retag it only

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JavaScript to connecto to a database. If you want to get data from a database, use jQuery and AJAX to get data from a .Net Web Service. It's pretty simple, and reusable.

You can build your own AJAX controls without jQuery, but I wouldn't...